# Sequential arithmetic operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a text input and user will write a string for example `10+20-10-2*2+4/2` and I want to do an arithmetic operation sequentially, which means I want to `(10+20)-(10)-(2)*(2)+(4)/(2)` and the result should be `20` according to above example.

In other words I want to do the arithmetic operation from the left, sequentially. Can anyone help me on this or may be some idea would be nice too. Thanks.

**Please ask me if need more information.**

```
$('#calculation').on('blur', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pattern=/^[-*/+0-9]+$/;
    value=$(this).val();
    if(value.match(pattern))
    {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('span.error').html('');
        //$('#total').val(eval(value));
        // No idea what to do

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('span.error').html('Invalid character');
    }
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It would be better to post what you've tried, and what the problem was.  Otherwise it sounds a bit like a "please give me the code" question....

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Isn't the result 20?

Comment: was about to say that. but why do you want to ignore order of operations? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations, the answer would then be 18.

Comment: This is for my friend's travel agency and he wants it in this way, not my choice.

Comment: What is the expected behavior for these case: `-45+23`, `++----+35*-++--43`, `4+++---++-35`, `45*-1`? Just a note, but your regex is too loose to invalidate many bad cases (e.g. `4+-**///3+`).

Comment: May be you can give me a better idea.

Comment: This might be overkill, but you could do research about the Interpreter Pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern

Comment: @SheikhHeera: I'm not too sure myself, either. My scientific calculator can evaluate those statement above by considering the first operation after a number as binary operator, and the rest as unary operator. For a pocket calculator (which is what your friend probably wants), the interpretation may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [**Try this:**](http://jsfiddle.net/8CgWu/)

```
var str = '10+20-10-2*2+4/2';
var numbers = str.replace(/ /g, '').split(/[-+*\/]/g);
var operators = str.replace(/ /g, '').split(/\d*/g);
operators.shift();

var result = +numbers[0];

for (var i = 0; i < operators.length - 1; i++) {
    result = eval( result + operators[i] + numbers[i + 1] );
}

alert(result)​;
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8CgWu/)

Comment: What if you start with a negative number?

Comment: @SamDufel, I got to run but feel free to edit my answer to fix that

Answer (score 0):

How about using eval to calculate the value.

```
$('#calculation').on('blur', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pattern=/^[-*/+0-9]+$/;
    value=$(this).val();
    if(value.match(pattern))
    {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('span.error').html('');
        //$('#total').val(eval(value));
        alert(eval(value));
        $('span.result').html(eval(value));

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('span.error').html('Invalid character');
    }
});​
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/gineshkumar/gRc9r/

Comment: May be you didn't read my question properly, eval won't do it sequentially from the left. eval will output `18` but I want it to be `20`.